# Can we identify an individual from their palm lines

Tags: human-biology

Can we identify an individual from their palm lines. Is there any uniqueness for palm lines among family members ?

Comment: as someone with a passing interest in biometrics - I think this is a good question.

Answer (score 1):

It was tricky searching for this through the morass of palmistry sites.  But, in the field of biometrics, I found the article ["Palm Print Recognition"](http://www.biometrics.gov/documents/palmprintrec.pdf), which states that (bolding mine):

> Because fingerprints **and palms** have both **uniqueness** and permanence..

it has been used for identification the same as fingerprints. The only reason it is not as widespread as fingerprints is largely due to logistics such as computer processing.

Answer (score -2):

Studies show correlations between palm primary lines and lip lines and palatal rugae patterns.Familial uniqueness should be there.

Comment: Welcome to Biology Stack Exchange.  This isn't really a full answer at the moment, however you can [edit] it to add more details - for example **which studies show this**?